# Replace part of output and simplify it

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have a code that give me :

```
E^(k (k n + (B - A k) HarmonicNumber[n])) (1 - r)^n
```

Now I want to replace HarmonicNumber[n] with:

```
\[Gamma] + Log[n]
```

to give me a new output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
out = E^(k (k n + (B - A k) HarmonicNumber[n])) (1 - r)^n;

replaced = out * E^(k (k n + (B - A k) (\[Gamma] + Log[n])))/
  E^(k (k n + (B - A k) HarmonicNumber[n]))
```

You can also do this as a replacement rule:

```
out /. HarmonicNumber[n] -> \[Gamma] + Log[n]
```